# Is possible to run a Python program through a kernel module written in C?

Tags: python, c

Using my RaspberryPi, I would like to create a kernel module that open a python program, which in turn, It will interface with GPIO.

Is possible to do it?

EDIT:

I will explain my reason: I have a circuit with some buttons, and a python program allow each button to play a sound. So, in my mind, if I open a python program through Kernel Module , I do just 1 call to user space, not as many as the buttons that plays the sounds.

Comment: I'd hesitate to say "it can't be done", but I'm fairly confident "it shouldn't be done".  Kernel modules should not be running user-space programs, in general.

Comment: I hate to be that guy who perpetuates the stereotype of people on SO just saying not to do something when someone asks how to do something, but I find it unlikely that there's a good reason to do this.

Comment: Conceptually, I agree with you, but I have not yet found a solution for my needs.

Comment: it's kinda weird, why would you do that? in general user may want to call a kernel module from a user space to do stuff not the inverse. asking why is to know if they are another way to do what you want to do, and to do it in the right way.

Comment: This seems to be a classic [XY-Problem](http://xyproblem.info)... Ask for what you actually need or want and not for your suggested solution.

Comment: I'd say it can be done, but it probably shouldn't be done. It can be done by calling `call_usermodehelper`. But note that the program will be run in usermode.

Comment: I will explain my reason: I have a circuit with some buttons, and a python program allow each button to play a sound. So, in my mind, if I open a python program through Kernel Module , I do just 1 call to user space, not as many as the buttons that plays the sounds.

Comment: @AlessioDonato You _really_ should have a look into the links in [Cédric Julien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56135066/7545157).

Answer (score 1):

The "good" way of doing what you need is to make your python program listen for gpio changes (with some modules like [inotify](https://pypi.org/project/inotify/) or [Watchdog](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/)).
In your python program, you'll be listening for GPIO changes, and then, according to the change, play the correct sound.
This is a good way to let communicate low level with user space programs.

If you're specifically using RaspberryPi to do this, take a look to the [GPIO module documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/python/README.md) (especially the `.when_pressed` part ;) )